# How to return a resolved promise without knowing which then() will be executed first

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a method that will return a promise. As shown below, there is two `then()` statements. Each of them contains a reference to a radioButton, and a specific method that will be executed according the selected radioButton.

I do not know in advance which radioButton will be chosen. what i want to achieve is, the method should return a resolved promise according to the selected radioButton. For example, if i choose `radioButton1` the first `then()` should not be executed and the method should return a resolved promise for `radioButton1`.

If i choose radioButton2 then second `then()` should not be executed and the method should return a resolved promise for `radioButton2`.

I hope I explained my point clearly. please let me know how to achieve it.

**code1**:

```
initComponents() {
return Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => this.getRadioButton1().on(RState.EVENT_ACTION, (action) => {
    this.onRadioButton1Changed.bind(this);
  }))
  .then(() => this.getRadioButton2().on(RState.EVENT_ACTION, (action) => {
    this.onRadioButton2Changed.bind(this);
  }));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a use case for promises; events happen more than once, but promises are only settled once. Separately, `this.onRadioButton1Changed.bind(this);` is a no-op, you aren't saving the bound function anywhere...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Why would you not just bind the two events and and resolve whatever needs to happen in the event handler?

Answer (score 1):

Normally in this situation you'd use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), which subscribes to promises in the array you give it and settles based on the first of them to settle (resolve or reject):

```
initComponents() {
  return Promise.race([
    new Promise(resolve => {
        this.getRadioButton1().on(RState.EVENT_ACTION, (action) => {
          this.onRadioButton1Changed.bind(this); // ???
          resolve(this); // or `resolve(action);` or `resolve({button: this, action});`
        })
    }),
    new Promise(resolve => {
        this.getRadioButton2().on(RState.EVENT_ACTION, (action) => {
          this.onRadioButton2Changed.bind(this); // ???
          resolve(this); // or `resolve(action);` or `resolve({button: this, action});`
        })
    })
  ]);
}
```

...but this doesn't seem like a use case for promises; events happen more than once, but promises are only settled once. Separately, `this.onRadioButton1Changed.bind(this);` is a no-op, you aren't saving the bound function anywhere.

Or avoiding duplication:

```
const promiseForButtonActionWithBind = (button, fn) => new Promise(resolve => {
  button.on(RState.EVENT_ACTION, (action) => {
    fn.bind(this); // ???
    resolve(this); // or `resolve(action);` or `resolve({button, action});`
  })
});
```

then

```
initComponents() {
  return Promise.race([
    promiseForButtonActionWithBind(this.getRadioButton1(), this.onRadioButton1Changed),
    promiseForButtonActionWithBind(this.getRadioButton2(), this.onRadioButton2Changed)
  ]);
}
```

Comment: would you please tell me what does no-op mean

Comment: @LetsamrIt - "No operation," something that does nothing.

Comment: would you please explain to me what does it mean that .bind(this) is no-op? and why i should save reference to it each time i call initiComponents()? i think as mentioned in the first code you posted, each time initComponents() is called, we will make binding? i hope my Point is clear, and please

Comment: @LetsamrIt - `bind` creates and returns a new function that, when called, will call the original with a specific `this`. Since you're not using `bind`'s return value, that work ends up doing nothing. `bind` doesn't modify the function you call it on, it creates a *new* function it returns.

Comment: Make the event happen only a single time by using `once` instead of `on`

Comment: @Bergi but the method initComponent will be called several times

Comment: @LetsamrIt And on every call, it would return a promise for the next button action that happens?

Comment: @LetsamrIt - Then you definitely want to remove the event handler -- both the one that fired (which `one` would do if this is jQuery) but also the handler on the other button (since you don't want that event anymore). But this is very strange. I'd tend to hook the event **once** (calling `initComponents` once, "init" is usually a one-off call), and have whatever this is just wait for the next event (without registering a new handler).